# Making a call to a thread object's method from the context of the thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a call to one of a thread object's methods from the context of the thread using the object's handle. However, this isn't working and instead the call to the method is being made from the context of the main thread. Is there any way around this?

Here's some example code:

```
import threading

class ThreadTest(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    print '\nInitializing ThreadTest\n'

  def call_me(self):
    ident = threading.current_thread().ident
    print '\nI was called from thread ' + str(ident) + '\n'

  def run(self):
    ident = threading.current_thread().ident
    print '\nStarting thread ' + str(ident) + ' for ThreadTest\n'
    self.call_me()

ident = threading.current_thread().ident
print '\nMain thread ID is ' + str(ident) + '\n'

tt = ThreadTest()
tt.start()
tt.call_me()

# Example Output:
#   Main thread ID is 140735128459616
#
#   Initializing ThreadTest
#
#   Starting thread 4400537600 for ThreadTest
#
#   I was called from thread 4400537600
#
#   I was called from thread 140735128459616
```

What I'm looking for is a way to make `tt.call_me()` be from the context of the thread such that `current_thread().ident` returns the same ID as it does when its called from the thread's run method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python class methods can be called from any thread. That goes for the threading.Thread class too. When you wrote:

```
tt.call_me()
```

You were saying, "whatever thread happens to be running this code, please call tt.call_me". Since you were in main thread, the main thread made the call. Python doesn't automatically proxy the call to the thread.

The self.call_me line in the run method worked just fine. The 'run' method is the thread and anything it calls is in that thread.

Comment: OK, that helps me understand why it's happening. So, is it possible to proxy the method call to the thread from the main thread?

Comment: I thought that would be the next question! Proxying method calls get complex. There are lots of tools for RPC to different processes (xmlrpc for example), but I don't know what is available for threads. One common solution is to create a queue. Your main thread writes it and your child thread reads it. Typically, you pass a data object and the thread figures out the right thing to do by reading its data.